# Use links in android dialog

Tags: android

I want to use links in android dialog and i ran into this weird problem, if i use this:

```
String part1 = "http://google.com";
String part2Label = "http://tests.fr";

tx1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\" + part1 + \">" + part1Label + "</a><br>" ) );
tx1.setAutoLinkMask(RESULT_OK);
tx1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

It works, but if i change the part1Label to "normal text", it stops working.
Did anyone ran into this issue before? I thought just using Html.fromHtml takes care to interpret of any html elements that i would like to use. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related (since you've said it works in the first option), but you have a couple of "" missing:

```
tx1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\" + part1 + \">" + part1Label + "</a><br>" ) );
```

should be:

```
tx1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + part1 + "\">" + part1Label + "</a><br>" ) );
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? The link doesn't respond to click? wrong URL? The example you wrote that works can't work as well, since it would have sent you to this URL "http://+ part1 +".